# "unresolved external symbol _triangulate" when using triangle library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, lnk2019

I'm currently using the [triangle library](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) in my program. The library contains only .c and .h files (no .lib). I get the following error on Visual Studio C++ 2010:

```
    1>data.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _triangulate referenced in function "struct triangulateio __cdecl readfile(void)" (?readfile@@YA?AUtriangulateio@@XZ)
```

The header file of my data.cpp is the following:

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

#include <WinSock2.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <GL/gl.h> //include the gl header file
#include <GL/glut.h> //include the glut header file
#include <GL/glu.h> //include the glut header file
#include <armadillo>

//Namespace
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

extern "C"
{
    #ifdef SINGLE
    #define REAL float
    #else /* not SINGLE */
    #define REAL double
    #endif /* not SINGLE */

    #include "triangle.h"
}
triangulateio readfile();

#endif
```

Data.cpp

```
 triangulate("pczAevn", &in, &mid, &vorout);
```

I've already made my program work with a Makefile of mine on Ubuntu, but I need to run my program on windows.
Feel free to ask for more information.

**EDIT #1:**
If you use the triangle library with VS, you have to put the following instruction on top of the triangle.c file `#define TRILIBRARY`
Now it compile. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: have you added the .lib file to the visual studio project's linker settings?

Comment: There is no lib; it's just a .c and a .h file.

Comment: What is 'readfile'?  Is that your code?  You might need to show your declarations of in, mid, vorout.

Comment: might I suggest using mingw to compile on Windows? your makefile might work as-is. Otherwise, have you tried putting your declaration of read file in your extern "C" and compiling then?

Comment: readfile is a function I've created, it's not part of the library.
Putting readfile in extern C didn't work.
`struct triangulateio in, mid, out, vorout;`
I'd love to compile it on windows but I need to use VS because of compatibility issues with an other program. Also, I have to use some .dll for my project (hardware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker can't find a definition for "triangulateio readfile()", if it's defined in the .c file my guess is that it isn't built. If you include it in the project it could work.